# Avoid a global state

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, software-design

Imagine some SOA. We have a few different services, of which the OperationContext is extended by some SecureOperationContext which makes sure certain security demands are met.

Assume furthermore that sometimes we might need to know a certain property from this SecureOperationContext somewhere else, in a place where there is and won't be this SecureOperationContext. For example a username for some sort of logging purpose.

Currently we're using something that looks and smells plain dirty. The fat's dripping of in my opionion.

Now, in some 'Common' library, there is a class defined with a ThreadStatic property: Username. I guess you can catch my drift: the security stuff sets this static global variable and lo and behold we have it available for logging puproses.

This thing bugs me, but on the other hand what else to do? I was thinking about creating a method that takes a string as parameter to handle this, but then all my methods need to still read that username property, which is  non-dry. 
So on one hand, this way everything is handled on the background, but I'm not just quite happy having to maintain some (global) class just to achieve this.

Any tips?

I'm not sure how to put it in less abstract terms, but here goes (in pseudo).

```
public WebService
{
    public Save(Car car)
    {
        // Some SecurityCOntext is known here, this holds top secret info, 
         //  like the username
        // and sets this into the golbal helper class UserNameManagemer 

        // car has for example a CreatedDate property (from an Interface),   
        //but I don't want handle do this propertyin every Create method can handled in some general piecei of code.       


        efcontainer.AddObjcect(car)
        e.SaveChanges()  -> 
        //Now savechanges will check the objects in the ObjectSatateManager 
        //and sets the apppriopriate property via the global thing.
    }
}
```

Now what to do to rid myself of this global variable!. Passing a username to SaveChanges is undesirable ass well, since we'd then still have to manually repat this for everything, which blows.

Comment: Your problem description is very abstract. Some code will help illustrate your problem. You may be helped by using action filters, but that really depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: All right, perhaps you find this more concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate the global property in a service. Define an interface for that service. Now, depend on that interface everywhere you need the data **by having a constructor parameter of that type**.

This is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and is a very important concept when you want to avoid problems as the one you currently have. A dependency injection container such as [Autofac](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can help if you have a big application, but is not strictly required.

**The most important thing is to understand dependency injection and have a well-defined [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), no matter whether you use a DI container or do it yourself.**

> The security stuff sets this static global variable and lo and behold we have it available for logging puproses.

This sounds like the data is determined dynamically. Note that you can still use a service to track the value. That service also knows whether the value is available or not. This way, you can better manage the temporal coupling that you have at the moment.

Edit: You can further improve the design by creating the client objects through a factory. That factory can ensure that the value is available, so it couples the lifetime of the client objects to the availability of the value. This way, you are sure to always act in a context where the value can be safely accessed.

Comment: So this 'service' e.g. IAccountInfoService would expose a property UserName. Because of my very limited experience with DI, save some simple constructor injection to facilitate testing, I'm not sure if this solves the 'problem' or just re-packages it. Still my security context would call something like AccountService.Username = "foo". The consuming code would in stead of reading the static property have an instance of IAccountInfoService and read the property. So yes, rid the static, is this better design solely because we're working against an interface? The data still has to pass ...

Comment: ... through an intermediate structure. Or perhaps I'm overthinking this? I've Mark Seeman's book on dependency injection on my desk, perhaps I'ts time to dig in :)

Comment: It also has the benefit of being able to control the lifecycle of the service, instead of the property. This means you get rid of ThreadStatic stuff that is scattered throughout the application. But you are right, this is not the cleanest solution yet. I added a further improvement to my answer, but this is probably already a big redesign - whereas just introducing the service is not. You have to decide for yourself....

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. I will be looking in to this. Currently Im refactoring large code base and have managed to rid 1000s of lines of WET code, with some simple Expression<>s. Now im looking for more anti-patterns :)